# i have 3 addeventlister each one call one button , how can change them to 1 function

Tags: javascript

ave 3 event how can change them to 1 function , and if button 1 clicked just rotate
card 1 and if button 2 clicked just rotate card 2 , Thanx for help me ,I want 3 event for
this ! is bad  cuz  need more cards

```
let btnshowrotate = document.querySelectorAll('.Showback')

let rotate = document.querySelectorAll('.rotate')
// [...document.querySelectorAll('.slide')]
let flipcardinner = document.querySelector('.flip-card-inner')
btnshowrotate[0].addEventListener('click', () => {

  rotate[0].style.transform = " rotateY(180deg)"

})

btnshowrotate[1].addEventListener('click', () => {

  rotate[1].style.transform = " rotateY(180deg)"

})

btnshowrotate[2].addEventListener('click', () => {

  rotate[2].style.transform = " rotateY(180deg)"

})
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



.flip-card {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    perspective: 1000px;

 
  }
  
  .flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
  
 
  .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
   
  }
  
  .flip-card-front {
    background-color: rgb(182, 180, 180);
    color: black;
    
   
  }
  


  /* .flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  } */
  /* .Showback:checked ~ .flip-card-inne{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  button.cheack ~ .flip-card-inner{
 
  } */

  .flip-card:hover button{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, -150px);
  }
  


  .Orginal-parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    height: 90vh;
   
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    transform: translate(0px, -50px);

  }

  article{
    border:1px solid skyblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
 
  }

  button{
    padding: 15px;
    outline: none;
    border:none;
    padding: 15px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition : 0.4s;
  }

  .flip-card-back {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    color: white;
   
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  
  }
 img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

   
  }

  .next,.prve{
  
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      display: flex;
      padding: 5px;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items:center;
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 20px;
      color:red;
      top:50%;
  }

  .next{
    right: 0;
  
  }

  .container-slider{
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.slide{
  padding: 15px;
display: none;
 transition: 0.4s linear;

}

.slide.active{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Flipcard.css">
</head>
<body>
  <article>
    <h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
    <h3>Hover over the image below:</h3> 
  </article>

<section class="Orginal-parent">

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner rotate">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <p  style="width:300px;height:300px;"> Adidass </p>
      <button class="Showback">Show For other</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner rotate" >
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <p  style="width:300px;height:300px;"> Puma </p>
      <button class="Showback">Show For other</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner rotate">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <p  style="width:300px;height:300px;"> Nike </p>
      <button class="Showback">Show For other</button>
 
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
      <p>We love that guy</p>
      
      <section class="container-slider">

        <figure class="slide active">
           <img src="img/2.webp" alt="">
        </figure>

        <figure class="slide">
          <img src="img/3.png" alt="">
        </figure>

        <figure class="slide">
           <img src="img/Smash-v2-Sneaker.webp" alt="">
        </figure>

  

    </section>
    
      <span   class="next">&#10095</span>
      <a  class="prve">&#10094</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</section>


<script src="Flipcard.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're askign for:

```
btnshowrotate.forEach((el, i) => el.addEventListener('click', () => rotate[i].style.transform = " rotateY(180deg)"))
```

Or to reduce even further, if you never use the btnshowrotate again, you can replace

```
let btnshowrotate = document.querySelectorAll('.Showback')
```

with

```
document.querySelectorAll('.Showback').forEach((el, i) => el.addEventListener('click', () => rotate[i].style.transform = " rotateY(180deg)"))
```

Comment: If this works for you, please be sure to mark the question as answered.  I'm new and can really use the points!

Comment: tnx so much men tnq tnq tnq and agin tnq you learn me  new method ;) i hope u are succed any work any whare thx :X